# Is removing !Test.isRunningTest() from Apex code save?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

We have to increase test coverage of the code and we have this method:

```
        if (this.settings.CreateChatterMessage__c && !Test.isRunningTest()) {
          if (isReviewer) {
            ConnectApiHelper.postFeedItemWithRichText('internal', this.jobApplication.Id, HMP_PrepareContentService.replaceVariablesInChatterMessageForReviewers(this.jobApplication, this.settings?.ChatterMessage__c, usrToWhichChatterMsgWillBeSent.Name));
        } else {
            ConnectApiHelper.postFeedItemWithRichText('internal', this.jobApplication.Id, HMP_PrepareContentService.replaceVariablesInChatterMessage(this.jobApplication, this.settings?.ChatterMessage__c));
        }
    }
}
```

The method postFeedItemWithRichText() uses postFeedElement() that posts Chatter feeds

Is there any risk of removing

```
!Test.isRunningTest()
```

from the code?
All unit tests pass with both using !Test.isRunningTest() and without !Test.isRunningTest()

Can it send a Chatter message to someone during the execution of unit tests or is it used only used to omit errors during unit tests?

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to avoid mixing unit test code with live code as much as possible. If you can remove it, I'd recommend that you do so.